# Highlight all occurrences inside source code of an Identifier in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Unfortunately now I am one of those people who are asking for help to find some individual setting inside Visual Studio but after quite a long time of searching I am simply giving up.

I need the following feature of both Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 turned on:

*If you click an identifier in your source code Visual Studio will highlight all other occurrences of this identifier with Grey.*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

[image]

I can't test this out myself, can't tell if it's a MSVS feature or Visual Assist. You might need Intellisense enabled for this.

Comment: I had this feature turned on ever since in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 and after a re-installation it was suddenly gone. But it was there ...

Comment: thanks for your update but your screen seems not to be included in the standard installation of Visual Studio Ultimate - so maybe it's really Visual Assist but I am pretty sure that I've never installed any VS Add-Ons or Plug-Ins ..

Comment: @marcwellman nope, it definitely is. Go to the toolbar -> Tools -> Options.

Comment: see my Options Dialog: http://www.pictureshoster.com/viewer.php?file=u9tnqm8i98jmdzzqpp.jpg

Comment: @marcwellman go to advanced - highlight references to symbol under cursor.

Comment: me too. see my picture again :)

Answer (score 1):

[This extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb) of Visual Studio will **Highlight all occurrences of selected word**

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb